# How to integrate libraries (clojars) into Lightable plugins

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lighttable

As exercise to gain experience with ClojureScript I am writing a LightTable Plugin and I find no way to successfully use any standard library, I read the official documentation and even updated it to reflect latest changes regarding paths etc.. I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j91Li9kL0t8&feature=youtu.be) and read the whole thread on the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/I1vFNuCm5zo)  trying the proposed solutions, even working with the latest github source without luck.

I tried including `core.async` or `cljs.http` (I know the embedded nodejs alternative, just as example) following the proposed workflow by Irakli on the Google discussion. Simplest possible scenario:

```
$ lein version
Leiningen 2.5.0 on Java 1.7.0_55 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (Mac OS X 10.9.5) and LT latest (0.7.2)
$ lein new lt-plugin sample
```

plugin project.clj->

```
(defproject sample "0.0.1"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [cljs-http "0.1.20"]
])
```

core file

```
  (ns lt.plugins.sample
  (:require [lt.object :as object]
            [lt.objs.tabs :as tabs]
            [lt.objs.command :as cmd]
            [cljs-http.client :as http]
            )
  (:require-macros [lt.macros :refer [defui behavior]]))

(defn get-users
  ""
  []
(let [response (http/get "https://api.github.com/users" {:with-credentials? false})]
      (prn (:status response))
      (prn (map :login (:body response)))))   ; evaluated correctly

(get-users) ; loads of errors like

WARNING: Referred var clojure.string/split does not exist at line 1 file:/Users/jaime/.m2/repository/noencore/noencore/0.1.16/noencore-0.1.16.jar!/no/en/core.cljs
```

I run lein deps, save, reload behaviours, restart, refresh plugin lists... all possible combinations tried, with the plugin folder within `~/Library/Application Support/LightTable/plugins` or outside.

Should I download the jars and put them manually into a lib folder? I guess `lein deps` is not working as I expect

Answer (score 0):

Yes currently seems that Cljs native or Cljx for that matter, doesn't resonate well with the LightTable UI.

Trying https://github.com/swannodette/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial you'll find that it doesn't take much. You can create a LT keybinding to open browser tab, navigate to project folder `index.html` and make another for reloading (as autoreload is a work in progress I think). Then another tab with the Cljs file while you have the cljsbuild auto running, refresh browser and changes should be witnessed.