# How to tie a string replace to a command in Light Table

Tags: regex, replace, clojure, find, lighttable

My work wants us to use left and right double quotes while typing documentation. I want to use the LaTeX style ones because I write papers in LaTeX often and I already type them automatically.

I am new to clojure but did manage to find this:

```
(def mystring "``quoted string''")
(clojure.string/replace mystring #"``|''" {"``" "“" "''" "”"})
```

This will output:

```
“quoted string”
```

So I want to tie this functionality to a command using keybindings. I was going to ask how to tie the above command. But then I read this bit on how standard clojure libraries don't integrate so well with LightTable: [How to integrate libraries (clojars) into Lightable plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062382/how-to-integrate-libraries-clojars-into-lightable-plugins)

I keep reading about regexs. Is there a way to apply a regex across an entire file?

What I'm thinking is I will type up the document and then at some point, hit (ctrl-i) or whatever and have it automatically replace the LaTeX characters with my work's desired characters.

If it was possible to have something auto-replace them while I type, that would be amazing. But I'm new to this so going with baby steps.

Comment: What version of light table are you using? If it is later than .5 or .7 i can definitely help you out with this.

Comment: I am using 0.7.2 at the moment. 

An alternative for this would be with auto-close enabled and functional for double-left-quote and double-right-quote. But I would still need to map a specific key to the double-left-quote. I'm not really ok with holding down alt and typing four numbers. :)

Comment: For now, I have settled on this keybinding as a workaround:
  [:editor "`" (:editor.open-pair "“”")]

This binds backtick to doing a double-left and double-right pair. I tried using open-pair and close-pair but close-pair never worked.

Comment: If you have any further questions, just let me know what version of lighttable you are using. Else you should answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using is the following key binding:

```
[:editor "ctrl-shift-q" (:editor.open-pair "“”")]
```

When I press my key combo, in this case control-shift-q, it drops the left-double-quote and right-double-quote into the document with my cursor in the middle.

I would still prefer to have something that replaced any double backtick "``" with a left-double-quote and any double apostrophe "''" with a right-double-quote but This works great for now.